# Run the spring application on the server and leave (nohup error)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, putty

**I want to run the jar file and shut down PuTTY.** 
First I type this:  ***root@:~# nohup java -jar spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &*** 
And I get these two lines: 
 **[2] 168168** 
**root@:~# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'**
*I'm a beginner in this so I don't know where the problem is*

Comment: And the problem is? It tells you that it is running in the background, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: That doesn't indicate a problem, it's just explaining what nohup is doing with input and output.

Comment: There is no problem here. What `nohup` is telling you is that it is ignoring any input. To suppress this message you can very well redirect its `stdin` to `/dev/null` like so.

Comment: All right, thank you so much. Do you know how to stop the app now?